# VM cannot communicate with host on a given port

Tags: virtual-machine, firewall, portforwarding

I'm doing some sort of school project where i have to make my vm (using virtualbox for hosting the vm) communicate with my host pc using port 6969.

The problem is that even after all the things I tried to open this particular port, the vm still says connection refused.
I'm using bridge adapter, the vm is a linux one, and my host is manjaro.
I cannot do any sudoer thing on the vm, it's mounted on an iso given by the school that is sure to be working fine (no one besides me had any problem with it) but is not giving me any admin rights.

Ssh connection are fine though, here are a few commands I ran on the vm :

```
$> nc -zvw10 192.168.1.40 6969
nc: connect to 192.168.1.40 port 6969 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

```
$> nc -zvw10 192.168.1.40 22
Connection to 192.168.1.40 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

And my opened and flushed iptables on host side :

```
$> sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any idea on things to try would help me so much.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: This seems like a better question for [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](//unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ok, i'll transfer it there